# Pass bound value into function parameter inside template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.myVar = something;
```

Can I do like this `ng-click=myFunction(a,b,{{myVar}}) ?`

Currently, I am getting an error.

Comment: will you please describe us in briefly?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

```
ng-click='myfunction(a,b,myVar)'
```

this should work

Comment: I'd like to add that variables a and b should be available from scope.

Comment: please provide more information.... a and b is scope variable? like $scope.a = 1; $scope.b = 2; if so, the above should work

Comment: Yes, exactly that. OP didn't show any details, so error might be caused be that too. Just small comment in case.